# How to give image relative path in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

I have folder structure like this for asp.net site :

[image]

now i run the site and result is like this :

[image]

here i am able to see the image "6".

now on click on : button , i am opening another page : dashboard.aspx:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnDashBoard").on("click", function () {
                debugger;
                window.location.href = "dashboard/dashboard.aspx";
                return false;
            });
        });
```

[image]
**here i am not able to see my image,** why?

my site.master html is like this :

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnDashBoard").on("click", function () {
                debugger;
                window.location.href = "dashboard/dashboard.aspx";
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input id="btnDashBoard" type="button" value="button" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="../Images/orderedList6.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried this `~/Images/orderedList6.png`?

Comment: Or this `/Images/orderedList6.png`

Comment: Yes, i did the same : http://postimg.org/image/k2fc421kp/

Answer (score 1):

You should let ASP.NET help you figure out the paths. There's a utility method on every `Control` named [`ResolveClientUrl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If you pass it the virtual path to a file, it will *resolve* its full path.

You can use it right in the `src` attribute for your `<img>` tag:

```
<img src='<%= Path.ResolveClientUrl("~/Images/orderedList6.png") %>' alt="" />
```

Comment: Sorry, i do not want to use <asp:image> control for image . i want to use html image element

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem which was, my path was for example: https://mysite/projects/index

And my html stored in database had an image with this src: ~/Images/myimg.png

So the path i was getting for the image was:

https://mysite/projects/index/~/Images/myimg.png

I just removed the "~" from my source and everything was solved, it lead to image path which was: https://mysite/Content/Images/myimg.png

Hope this helps